# Ambiguity in interfaces

Tags: object, interface, reference, ambiguity

```
interface A
{
  int a = 10;
}

interface B
{
  int a = 10;
}

class Access implements A, B
{
}

class Demo
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Access ac = new Access();
    System.out.println(ac.a);   // line #1
  }
}
```

Line #1 causes ambiguity. How do I remove it? Is it not possible to have same variable name of different interfaces?

Comment: just for clarification: "variables" in interfaces are by default `static final` i.e. "constants"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to reference the two variables as `A.a` and `B.a` respectively;

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println( ((A)ac).a);   

or
System.out.println( ((B)ac).a);
```

If you have variables which are conflicting then you need to use resolution to access value of particular interface.